# Django - display "work-in-progress/loading" after form submit until result is returned

Tags: html, django, progress-bar

I have a online pricing webpage where customer can input some data, then submit the form to get the price returned. How to display a "work-in-progress/loading/calculating"kind of thing temporarily before the final result (e.g. price) is calculated/returned.

below is the simplified code from my web:

**Main html (post_list.html) (Note: I am using htmx to help partially update the page result)**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" hx-post="{% url 'post_list' %}" hx-target="#num_1" hx-target="#num_2" hx-target="#result">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
            <label>num_1:</label>
            <input type="text" name="num_1" value="" placeholder="Enter value" />
            </div>
            <div>
            <label>num_2:</label>
            <input type="text" name="num_2" value="" placeholder="Enter value" />
            </div>

            <br />
            <div id="num_1">{{ num_1 }}</div>
            <br />
            <div id="num_2">{{ num_2 }}</div>
            <br />
            <div id="result">{{ result }}</div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**post_list_snippet.html**

```
<html>

    <div>
            <label>first_number:</label>
            <span id="num_1"> {{ num_1 }} </span>
    </div>

    <div>
            <label>second_number:</label>
            <span id="num_2"> {{ num_2 }} </span>
    </div>

    <div>
            <label>calculation_result:</label>
            <span id="result"> {{ result }} </span>
    </div>

</html>
```

**view.py**

```
def post_list(request):
    result = ""
    num1 = ""
    num2 = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = request.POST.get('num_1')
        num2 = request.POST.get('num_2')
        result = int(num1) + int(num2)

    if request.headers.get('Hx-Request') == 'true':
        # return only the result to be replaced
        return render(request, 'blog/post_list_snippet.html', {'num_1': num1,'num_2': num2,'result': result})
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'num_1': num1,'num_2': num2,'result': result})
```

Comment: Did you find the answer yourself? please share it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using a Bootstrap 5 loader. Add all of below code to **main.html**

Step 1: Add html element containing a loader

Make sure style="display: none;"

```
<div id="loadingModal" style="display: none;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" disabled>
      <span class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Loading...
    </button>
</div>
```

Step 2: Add js function to display loader when form is submitted

```
<script>

function openLoader() {
    document.getElementById("loadingModal").style.display = "block";
  }

</script>
```

Step 3: Assign js function to onsubmit in your form element

```
<form onsubmit="openLoader()" method="POST" hx-post="{% url 'post_list' %}" hx-target="#num_1" hx-target="#num_2" hx-target="#result">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...form contents here...
</form>
```

When form is successfully submitted, the loading modal will appear, and then disappear when your view finishes execution and redirects.

Comment: simple and work like a charm. I used d-flex and started with d-none class (because d-flex don't honor display:none) and on submit the d-none class was removed.